# 'locate' command in terminal. Why is it so fast?

Tags: command-line, locate

Searching a keyword in linux terminal using the `locate` command gives answer in a short time.
What is the search algorithm used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system creates a data base of all the files in the computer. So when you search trough `locate` the command doesn't really checks the whole file-system but only the database, it does a binary search algorithm which is fast like looking up a word in a dictionary.  That's why it's so fast (and handy).

Such database is updated regularly; you may have seen it work sometimes when you install a new package: `updating mlocate...`. You can find more information about how it works by executing in a terminal:

```
man locate

man updatedb
```

Comment: it's also buggy:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mlocate/+bug/1190696

Comment: So it's like the Windows search indexer...

Comment: I don't see a binary search in https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/mlocate.git/tree/src/locate.c , but I may be missing something. That code appears to just iterate over every db entry.

Answer (score 4):

It uses a database. The database searched by default is located at:

```
/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
```

Downside of locate is that it is NOT real time.

From the man page:

> DESCRIPTION
>          locate  reads  one or more databases prepared by updatedb(8) and writes
>          file names matching at least one of the PATTERNs  to  standard  output,
>          one per line.